# libgdx -> camera and viewports

Tags: android, libgdx

I have made my game, which scaled accordingly to a % of the screen width with the `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` method, and it works perfectly on all screens.

Now I am trying to learn viewports, but seems like there is a lot more trouble, like when does it take in world coordinated or when does it take actual screen pixels.

**Do I have to constantly convert beetwen these two measurments?** It seems like there is alot more trouble, than if I just scale it the old fasion way...

I can use the whole screen, and manually make the pictures non streched, if I used a FitViewport I would have like blackbars and the game would be totally different.

Any clear suggestions to why to use these ports, cause I cannot seem to understand them...

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. The amount of converting between world and screen coordinates is the same whether you use a Viewport or a Camera directly. Viewport just makes it easier to deal with various aspect ratios. Without seeing the code you are referring to, there's not much more to say about it.

Comment: Well if I make a game where objects fall from the sky, if I use FitViewport, than the objects will spawn either not on top of the screen, or they can not spawn from the most left to the most right side of the screen. So for my game I couldnt have used the viewports, because it would look ugly, so I did it with %, so I sitll dont get why people would use viewports, if the game is stationary...

Comment: For the vast majority of games, ExtendViewport is the only viewport that should be used for non-UI stuff. FitViewport is a lazy way to not worry about scaling at the expense of having black bars.

Comment: But let's say my sprites that are falling down and have a spawn range from the left to the right screen edge, well because I didn't use cameras... Now if I would use a camera, and go on a tablet, the spawn rate would be only like in the middle screen, because even extendviewport would just make the background extend left and right..., or would the sprites be also spawned from the edge to edge? but if that happens, then the sprites will be also smaller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that you **do not have to do anything** especially making any conversion.

[Viewport](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) is a kind of tool that handling your app's rendering on many types of screens (I mean many other ratios) and you do not have to worry about it anymore.

Only thing you have to do is to "tell" viewport what is the size of your screen and to handle screen resizing by updateing the viewport. Then you are treating your app like it would be always for example *800 x 600px* no matter how it looks actually.

The way your app will render depends on what viewport implementation you will use. For example:

- **FitViewport** will fit your screen to device and add some black bars
- **FillViewport** will fit your screen to device and cut off overflowing part
- and so on...

The a look at [official Viewport libGDX tutorial](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports). Also you can take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255098/libgdx-box2d-screen-resolution/32258204#32258204) to get some information how to deal with viewports.

Comment: Umm, doesn't input proccessor use screen coordinates, as would the logic??? Or is it possible using those visual pixel (800X600) for everything, because that would make sense... One more thing, seems like extendViewport is the most useful one, or the only one useful, but how do I make the background take all the screen, while sprites are relative to the screen also, because ExtendViewport extends it somehow in one way and all is weird... Do you have any examples? sorry for bothering, but am really confused, because I made a game without any these things and scaled perfectly...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rjtPprqD <-- current code, I am using 800x600, but if the window is not 800x600, and I move the screen in desktop mode higher, sprite stays at same location, but it should move up

Comment: You should take a look at another libgdx'es SO topics (I had some answers in topics like this) - also the tutorial providing nice introduction that should clear out some problems :) Answering your question about background - you can create many stage's with many viewports for example stage with FillViewport for background and second stage with ExtendViewport for ui buttons etc... However do not creating very many stages (like >10) due to performance issues

Comment: Ye gonna add 1 stage for UI and 1 stage for background and got everything else working, because I had WIDTH and HEIGHT set-up as each other and nothing was working... Although is it necessary to make a stake for background??? can I maybe just draw it wiht Gdy.graphics.getHeight and width... and then everyhing else with a camera?

Comment: Guess you can but why :) Less means (usually) better - using prepared mechanism means more time to do other things but it is on your own

Comment: ye I guess, but I am still getting so many errors with extended, like when extending screen to be wider, the main screen picture positions itself always to the left, and stage 1, which is the score UI, positions itself to the right... , it is behaving weird, ye but I am trying to do everything with this